# Mostrar resultado SQL como entero

Tags: sql-server

El departamento de recursos humanos necesita mostrar el número de empleado, el apellido, el salario y el salario aumentado en un 10,5% (expresado como número entero) de cada empleado. Etiqueté la columna como `New Salary`.

La hago así:

```
SELECT [numero de empleado]
    ,apellido
    ,salario + (salario * 0.105) AS New_salary
FROM empleados
```

Perfecto, solo necesito que los valores del calculo del salario sean enteros. ¿Alguna idea? Actualmente me los arroja de esta forma:

> 3315.0000000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes lograr haciendo un `CAST` a `INT`:

```
CAST((salario * 1.105) AS INT)
```

Código:

```
SELECT 
    [numero de empleado],
    apellido,
    salario,
    CAST((salario * 1.105) AS INT) as New_salary 
FROM empleados
```

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración de la solución](http://rextester.com/GYX48447)</kbd>

Comment: creo que es la solucion pero no se por que no me corre, no me reconoce las columnas

Comment: ¿Qué error te envía?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '@salario'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'salario'.

Comment: Eso es debido a que @salario es una variable que yo puse en la demostración, para tu prueba quítale la `@` y pon tal cual el nombre de tus columnas :)

Comment: jajajja bro lo se se la quite sigue igual me dice por ejemplo en CAST  incorrect syntax near 'CAST'

Comment: Se me fue una coma antes del AS INT, chéca nuevamente mi hermano

Comment: hermano la puse aqui: CAST ((SALARIO * 1.105), AS INT) AS NEW SALARY

Comment: y aun no me corre

Comment: Es que no lleva coma, revisa mi respuesta actualizada :)

Comment: ok ya lo probe me corrio, pero una pregunta cuando formule la pregunta puse 10.5 como el decimal y lo dividi y me dio 0.105 y tu en tu ejemplo pusiste 1.105 es esa la forma de ese porciento?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que esto `salario + (salario * 0.105)` es lo mismo que esto `(salario * 1.105)` solo que el primero son dos operaciones y el otro solo es una, pero el resultado es el mismo

Comment: OK, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

lo que podríamos hacer para calcular los datos que tu quieres
Seria utilizar Round()

Donde el Syntax es el siguiente:

```
SELECT ROUND(tu_columna ,decimales) FROM tu_tabla;
```

Comment: brother pero esa consulta solo seria para un campo y quiero una consulta completa me doy a entender:

Comment: eso seria para traer la columna salario de forma entera  pero no me serviria para la consulta completa cuando le multiplice el porciento

Comment: Si, tienes razón tal ves yo fui quien no entendió la pregunta.
Pero creo que puedes utilizar la respuesta de nuestro compañero @Flxtr
Que creo que es la solución a tu problema